# Redirect for path but only for specific domain

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

We have different domains that are hosted on our server. Recently one of the main sections of our site has been moved to another server and been given a subdomain:

```
http://www.mysite.com/store
```

Has been moved to

```
http://store.mysite.com
```

Within our apache `VirtualHost` we wanted to redirect all traffic from the old domain to the new one:

```
Redirect permanent /store http://store.mysite.com
```

The problem is, we have other hosted sites that are being redirected now:

```
http://www.othersite.com/store
http://api.greatsite.com/store
```

We don't want this. How can I only have apache do redirects if  `http://www.mysite.com/store` which has the `/store` path, and ignore other domains with `/store`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite based code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?store(/.*|)$ http://store.mysite.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: So, this rule means ONLY redirect if the user is accessing `www.mysite.com/store/*` ?

Comment: Made an edit, now above rule will handle all `www.mysite.com/store/*` URLs.

Comment: Hmm, made the changes but viewing `http://api.greatsite.com/store` still redirects to `http://store.mysite.com` which I don't want. Only `www.mysite.com` should.

Comment: Did you comment out your Redirect rule and did you use RewriteCond as shown above?